# Are there any filters or sample code that actually fully use rcSource and rcTarget in VIDEOINFOHEADER?

Tags: video, directshow, directshow.net

The MSDN documentation for DirectShow documents an elaborate scheme for the rcSource and rcTarget members of VIDEOINFOHEADER and VIDEOINFOHEADER2 where portions of an input frame can be stretched or shrunk onto portions of an output frame.

[Source and Target Rectangles in Video Renderers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%22Source%20and%20Target%20Rectangles%20in%20Video%20Renderers%22)

However I haven't found any filters or sample code that actually use rcSource and rcTarget in this way. In the sample code I've found rcSource and rcTarget are either set to (0,0,0,0) or (0,0,width,height).

Is full support for rcSource and rcTarget so rare that it's not even worth implementing? Should I explicitly reject rcSource or rcTarget values that are not zero or default? At the moment I don't even have a reference implementation to test general values of rcSource and rcTarget against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of filter you are developing? Although while this may have some influence on the answer, you already answered your question - it is indeed very rare. It is typical for the filters to negotiate media types individually and they don't have any crop information to choose extent other than full video frame. As a result, you are having hard time finding filters that support or even care for those rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Roman. I'm working on several types of filter - sources, sinks, demuxers, muxers, transforms (in-place and copy) but not video renderers at the moment. I suppose the important questions is how to treat rcSource and rcTarget safely so that my code won't fail when connected to one of the rare filers that do actually use rcSource and rcTarget.

Comment: You should be good just by putting assertions that cover three scenarios: (1) rects are empty, (2) they extend to full frame, or (3) they cover full frame plus strides are extended per video renderer requests. You are unlikely to see anything else, and thus you can take the assumption and not implement other flavors of media types.

Answer (score 0):

One DirectShow filter that does use rcTarget - the Microsoft Line 21 Decoder filter for decoding closed caption data. Presumably this is used for positioning and masking the closed caption data relative to the video.